# Cómo agregar Distinc a mi consulta con Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Ahi esta la consulta creada con criteria APi y la consulta sql estoy trabajando con SyBase. lo que no se es como agregar el distinc en el código de criteria. recién estoy tocando criteria y me piden que lo hago con esa api en el trabajo si que no puedo implementar otra forma.

```
public List<SelectGenerico> getProductsMariscos() throws DataAccessException {
    
    ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
    DetachedCriteria criteria;
    List<SelectGenerico> resultado;
    
    try {
        proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("ori.codigo").as("id"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("ori.descripcion").as("descripcion"));

        criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TSisPro.class, "sisPro")
            .createAlias("sisPro.origen", "ori")
            .createAlias("sisPro.subSector", "sse")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("sisPro.codSis", ConstantPreciosMar.ID_SISTEMA))
            .add(Restrictions.in("sse.codigo", ConstantPreciosMar.TIPO_PRODUCTO))
            .setProjection(proj)
            .addOrder(Order.asc("ori.descripcion"))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SelectGenerico.class));

        resultado =  (List<SelectGenerico>) this.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria,-1,0);
        
        if (resultado == null || resultado.size() == 0) {
            throw new DataAccessException("No se encontraron productos para la busqueda."){};
        }
        return resultado;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage()){};
    } finally {
        proj = null;
        criteria = null;
        resultado = null;
    }
}
```

```
SELECT ori_cod, ori_des 
FROM odepa..T_origen, odepa..T_sis_pro, odepa..T_subsector , ( select distinct mer_ori_cod from odepa..T_not_mer_prod_mar ) prod_mar 
WHERE ori_cod = sis_pro_ori_cod 
AND sse_cod = sis_pro_sse_cod 
AND sis_pro_sis_cod = 5 
AND sis_pro_sse_cod IN(21, 22, 23) 
AND ori_cod = prod_mar.mer_ori_cod 
GROUP BY ori_cod ORDER BY ori_des
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta fue la solucion que encontre por si a alguien le sirve.

```
public List<SelectGenerico> getProductsMariscos() throws DataAccessException {
    
    ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
    DetachedCriteria criteria;
    DetachedCriteria criteria2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TNotMerProdMar.class);
    List<SelectGenerico> resultado;
    
    try {
        proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("ori.codigo").as("id"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("ori.descripcion").as("descripcion"));

        criteria2.setProjection(
            Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("ori.codigo"),"origenCodigo")));



        criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TSisPro.class, "sisPro")
            .createAlias("sisPro.origen", "ori")
            .createAlias("sisPro.subSector", "sse")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("sisPro.codSis", ConstantPreciosMar.ID_SISTEMA))
            .add(Restrictions.in("sse.codigo", ConstantPreciosMar.TIPO_PRODUCTO))
            .setProjection(proj)
            .addOrder(Order.asc("ori.descripcion"))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SelectGenerico.class));

        resultado =  (List<SelectGenerico>) this.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria,-1,0);
        
        if (resultado == null || resultado.size() == 0) {
            throw new DataAccessException("No se encontraron productos para la busqueda."){};
        }
        return resultado;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage()){};
    } finally {
        proj = null;
        criteria = null;
        resultado = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explica brevemente el funcionamiento de tu código. Ten en cuenta que otros más adelante podrían tener tu mismo problema, y puede que no comprendan lo que hace. Lee [answer].